# How Ctrl Z works actually

Tags: c++, windows

Just for curious mind. During problem solving many question says,"Input will be terminated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>". I know its "EOF(End Of File)" But...

```
while(scanf("%d",&a)==1)
{ cout<<"OK"<<endl;}

while(scanf("%d",&a)!=EOF)
{cout<<"OK"<<endl;}

while(cin>>a)
{cout<<"OK"<<endl;}
```

Above 3 will be terminated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.

```
while(scanf("%d",&a))
{cout<<"OK"<<endl;}
```

It will give OK by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>.
    and

```
while(1){cin>>a;
cout<<"OK"<<endl;}
```

Its a infinte loop.

I want to know how <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> works on a program termination. What is the reason behind it. Please answer in details.

Comment: Oh right, then nevermind.

Comment: @NafeeurRahman: you caused some confusion by not mentioning that you were talking specifically about Windows - people assumed you were talking about a proper OS, where Ctrl Z does something different. I've added a Windows tag to your question now to avoid further confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> does not terminate your program. It also doesn't pause its execution. It's a 0x1A byte that is interpreted by `iostream` and `stdio` methods to be EOF (end-of-file). After that character is read from the console, nothing is read further and the method that is reading it returns. In the case of `iostream`, `std::ios::eof()` becomes true.

You would notice in your last case that if you structured it as:

`while(cin >> a) { ... }`

It would exit like the others.

Comment: Thank you for your ans. I want to know again why Ctrl+Z is not working properly for 4th case? After pressing Ctrl+Z it also taking input. But why?

Comment: @NafeeurRahman, in the 4th case `scanf` will return `EOF` (usually -1) when you enter Ctrl+Z, so the loop repeats.

Comment: At a lower level, Windows [`ReadFile`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365467) also gets involved. For a console input handle in the default [`ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683167) mode, if the buffer it reads in starts with Ctrl+Z (0x1A), `ReadFile` sets `lpNumberOfBytesRead` to 0. AFAIK, this is undocumented.